# Why the modulo/remainder operator calculated is wrong for large numbers?

Tags: javascript, bignum, wolframalpha

I am trying to understand why I am not able to calculate the right modulo using JavaScript. The operation I have tried is:

*Wrong answer*

```
28493595674446332150349236018567871332790652257295571471311614363091332152517 % 6 = 4
```

The result should be 1.

```
28493595674446332150349236018567871332790652257295571471311614363091332152517 % 6 = 1
```

I have tried to convert this number to BN but unfortunately I always get the same answer. However if you use wolfram alpha or another math software it returns the right answer.

What's going on? What have I been doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean modulo?

Comment: It's not the modulo operator, but the remainder operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder

Comment: Also.. that number is way too big for JavaScript.

Comment: `28493595674446332150349236018567871332790652257295571471311614363091332152517 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER // true` - It's wayyy to big for normal numbers. Consider using a BigInt instead.

Comment: Use [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), here is an example `BigInt('28493595674446332150349236018567871332790652257295571471311614363091332152517') % BigInt(6)`

Comment: just use bigInt `28493595674446332150349236018567871332790652257295571471311614363091332152517n % 6n === 1n`

Comment: @Titus BigInt literals can be made without the function. `6n` is a big int.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Using the function illustrates better what is going on there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integer number range in JavaScript is +/- 9007199254740991 (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER). Your number is simply out of range for JS.

You can also use the BigInt notation to get the right answer.
    `28493595674446332150349236018567871332790652257295571471311614363091332152517n % 6n`

See [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin/4375743#4375743)

Comment: For clarity, the `n` suffix at the end of the number tells the interpreter that the preceding number is a `bigint`.